# Retriving Date from Sharepoint List DateTime column adds one day

Tags: c#, datetime, sharepoint

I am trying to retrieve dates from a SharePoint List with C#. The dates are created with a SharePoint datepicker. My problem is that SharePoint adds 1 day. I have tried `.ToLocalTime()` and `.ToUniversalTime()` right before and I save the time to a list. I have searched different solutions, none of which have been successful. Does anybody know how to convert the date?

My code:

```
public List < DateTime > GetHolidays(ClientContext context) {

  List < DateTime > holidayDates = new List < DateTime > ();
  var items = LoadListHoliday(context);

  if (context != null) {
    foreach(ListItem listItem in items) {
      DateTime date = (DateTime) listItem["u12q"];
      holidayDates.Add(date.Date.ToLocalTime());
    }
  }
}

return holidayDates;
}
```

> LoadListHoliday(context);

is a method that retrives the list.

Answer (score 0):

solved it like this:

```
  foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
                {
                    DateTime date = System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime((DateTime)listItem["u12q"]);
                    holidayDates.Add(date.Date);
                }
```